# Computing the similarity between two line drawings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python program where people can draw simple line drawings using a touch screen. The images are documented in two ways. First, they are saved as actual image files. Second, I record 4 pieces of information at every refresh: the time point, whether contact was being made with the screen at the time (1 or 0), the x coordinate, and the y coordinate.

What I'd like to do is gain some measure of how similar a given drawing is to any other drawing. I've tried a few things, including simple Euclidian distance and similarity between each pixel, and I've looked at Frechet distance. None of these can give what I'm looking for.

The issues are that each drawing might have a different number of points, one segment does not always immediately connect to the next, and the order of the points is irrelevant. For instance, if you and I both draw something as simple as an ice cream cone, I might draw ice cream first, and you might draw the cone first. We may get an identical end result, but many of the most intuitive metrics would be totally thrown off.

Any ideas anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a problem formulation question and not a specific programming question.

Comment: what about scaling up or down, translating and\or rotating? Is an icecream cone no longer a cone if it is on its side and bigger?

Answer (score 1):

if you care about how similar a drawing is to another, then there's no need to collect data at every refresh.  just collect it once the drawer is done drawing

Then, you can use fourier analysis to break the images down in to frequency domains and run cross correlations on that

or some kind of 2D cross correlation on the images, I guess